# Create tablespace "error in creating database file, access denied (OS 5)"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, tablespace

I try to create a database file. I've checked the route and everything, I've tried several times to create the tablespace (I've changed to capital letter, the ' for "...) like this...

```
create tablespace uinstitucion datafile 'C:\app\uinstitucion\oradata\uinstitucion\uinstitucion.dbf' size 500M ;
```

> file create error, unable to create file", "unable to open file", "(OS 5) access denied" (but I am logged as SYSTEM!)

... as you can see, I was just lead to several errors. What can I do? What am I doing wrong? I'm desperate since yesterday, and my teacher does not seem to notice the exact error.
I've also tried the order like

```
CREATE TABLESPACE lmtbsb DATAFILE 'file_path/lmtbsb01.dbf' SIZE 50M
EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE;
```

but it leads me to the same error.
I'm sorry I cannot post a picture, it would be more descriptive, but I am not allowed yet.

Comment: It can't be mysql and oracle. Please remove one of those tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run your SQLplus as an administrator and then connect and try to execute it.

You error says that you have no privileges to create file. This comes from operating system. Path looks for Windows so please try right click on SQLplus (or any other client you're using), choose run as administrator and then continue.